# Problem with variable assignment within foreach loop (R)

Tags: r, foreach, variable-assignment

I am trying to define a VAR model for a multivariate timeseries within a foreach loop. Within the model definition I am using the exogen parameter to define additional features which I dont want to predict within the var model.

```
set.seed(2019)
dataframe <- foreach(

  SOME CODE...

  mod_var <- tryCatch(
    expr = {
      vars::VAR(
        y = train[, c(target, endo_var)],
        type = "const",
        exogen = train[, exo_var],
        lag.max = lag_max_var,
        ic = "AIC"
      )
    },
    error = function(e) {
      return(NULL)
    }
  )

SOME MORE CODE...

)
```

My problem is when I click through the script manually without executing the entire loop, everything works fine. However when the loop is executed I get the error message

My assumption that this might have something to do how the foreach function distributes evaluations proved to be correct since the loop worked when I used to global assignment operator to set the object I give to the exogen paramteter like so

```
set.seed(2019)
dataframe <- foreach(

  SOME CODE...

  exogen_matrix <<- train[, exo_var]
  mod_var <- tryCatch(
    expr = {
      vars::VAR(
        y = train[, c(target, endo_var)],
        type = "const",
        exogen = exogen_matrix,
        lag.max = lag_max_var,
        ic = "AIC"
      )
    },
    error = function(e) {
      return(NULL)
    }
  )

SOME MORE CODE...

)
```

Since I have read that it is not good practice to make global assignments within loops I wanted to ask if there is another way to ensure objects are correctly assigned within a foreach loop

Comment: That's not even valid `foreach` syntax.

Comment: sorry, I copy pasted it out of my code wrong. Is it correct now?